# US Assault class gear detail in Battlefield 4

Tags: equipment, airsoft

I am an airsoft player and would like to reproduce the US Assault class in Battlefield 4 as seen below.

[image: Us Assault class]

For the base layer, I'm assuming any sand balaclava, sand gloves and multicam pants would do. I don't know if Dark Earth combat shirts with sand sleeves exist.

For the head part, A sand Mich 2000 or similar, sand goggles, and a Peltor Comtac.

I have absolutely no idea of what type of chest rig/plate carrier is used. Also the belt is some sort of harness ( I don't know the exact word ).

If anyone could help me, a name or a link to similar equipment would be nice.

Comment: I am wondering if you could post a photo of your finished loadout because I am planning to bye the same loadout. Thanks for all the information. Sincerely Coussement Benjamin
CGB

Comment: I didn't have the time to buy all of the equiment yet ( barely any actually, I'm pretty busy these days... ), but here's a video of someone who has a few parts of the loadout : [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3gbRCth0Ps)

Comment: the backpack is a tier-one quality solutions slim bag.... if you would like to know.... i have been searching everywhere to find out what it is... i found it by accident when i wasnt even looking for it at the time...

Comment: The backpack is an M9 Medical Backpack if you were wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From top to bottom:

- OPS-CORE: FAST Ballistic high cut (XP) Helmet: Tan + LUX LINER H-NAPE
- Princeton Tec Charge MPLS
- MS2000 Strobe
- Peltor Comtac 3
- XGO Phase 4 Neck Gaiter in Coyote Brown
- ESS Profile NVG Military Goggles black with gray Lenses
- LBT 6094 in Coyote Brown
- VIP IR LED Strobe Light
- SAFARILAND 6378USN ALS® Low Signature Holster Multicam
- New Eagle Industries USMC MOLLE Coyote FB 9MM Mag Pouch
- Two red chem lights
- Blackhawk S.T.R.I.K.E 40MM Grenade Molle Pouch in Coyote Tan
- LBT-6159 Modular Double M4/M14/MP5 Mag Pouch in Coyote Brown
- Double M67 Pouch in Coyote (NSN 8465-01-558-5185)
- Combat First Response Pouch (Condor)
- Tactical Tailor 40mm Belt 12rd in Foliage
- YATES 313 Lightweight Assault Harness in Terra
- CRYE Combat Pant AC Multicam + AirFlex™ Combat Knee Pads in Khaki
- CRYE G3 Combat Shirt™ Khaki 400
- TACOPS® M9 Assault Medical Backpack in coyote + IR reflective reversed Velcro Flag +     three red and one white chem light
- FR FAST ROPE GLOVE COYOTE (Oakley)
- Lowa Elite Desert Ws

All I didn't find is the waist pouch.

I'm building the same loadout and I hope You have success.